# Looking for shopping cart ONLY app or hosted service recommendation

Tags: e-commerce, cart, shopping-cart

I have been tasked with selling made-to-order products online. We have a web-based product configurator and order processing system set up that produces prices, interfaces with our inventory system, etc.

I've reviewed Magento and Ubercart and they appear to do too much; the management perceives integrating something like that as an unnecessary abstraction from what we already have going. In addition, our pricing structure is arranged in such a way that it would be an overwhelming task for me to extend the pricing system in a feature-rich ecommerce platform.

I need to be able to send an arbitrarily generated product description and price to a cart and then have it handle the sale checkout and secure payment gateway headaches.

Is there anything out there that allows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with a fairly-basic Drupal site and rolled my own very-basic cart module.